# How do I save multiple fieldsets using the play framework form tag?

Tags: forms, playframework, playframework-1.x, fieldset

I have multiple fieldsets containing radiobuttons and an input box on a page. I was given this app to maintain and currently the data is saved by iterating over a `Scope.Params` parameter, picking out each value, using `params.get()` and passing them along to a method to save.

What is a good way to execute this? Will I always have to use a `Scope.Params` parameter? I know one can parameterize the values of the input fields of the form in the action that is called upon submit. How do I do it for a fieldset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In controllers you can automatically get parameters if you have in your method signature.

Let's say you have a from `createUser.html` calls a `POST` method in your template. It is in `UserController` and `createUser`.

In form you have:

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
```

so in you controller if you have a method like this:

```
pulic statid void createUser(String firstname, String lastname, int gender) {

User user = new User(firstname, lastname, gender);

...

}
```

So you don't necessarily need to get parameters separately.

EDIT -> In order to save multi-fields for same for you could use arrays like:

in form you could have: `<input type="text" name="firstname[]" />`

in controller:

```
pulic statid void createUser(String[] firstname ...) {

for (int i=0; i<firstname.length; i++) {

...

}

...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am aware of this method, and this is what I do for most forms. However, to give you an idea, let me use your example. There will be multiple First Name, Last Name and Gender inputs on one page. I am asking how do I deal with that.

Comment: Ok, ill try it and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it a while ago. I am getting a NPE. Have you used this anywhere before?

Comment: Yep, I've used this in many forms. The key point is you need to use "form" i.e. #{form @methodName(), method:'POST'} ... #{/} and input fields names should be same with your parameters in methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: Aah. I used the plain HTML form tag. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @huzefy Can I use HTML inside form tags?

Comment: yep sure.. you could use html tags anywhere.. this is easy use of play framework groovy template tags.